Trying to get scoped param value out of vega-lite spec
Hey I am trying to emit my tickSelection parameter out of this vega-lite spec.
I am trying to pass it using a signal by grabbing the selectedBoxId signal within the scope where I am drawing ticks. I don't think I am doing it right. I am not getting any response from my signal listener:
parameterChartView = new View(parse(parameterCharts.value)).renderer('canvas').initialize('#view').run();
parameterChartView.addSignalListener('selectedBoxId', (name, value) => {
    console.log('Selected Box ID:', name, value);
});

Vega-lite spec:
return {
        $schema: VEGALITE_SCHEMA,
        config: {
            font: globalFont,
            tick: { thickness: 2 }
        },
        width: 600,
        height: 50, // Height per facet
        data: {
            values: parameterRanges // {boxId: number; parameterId: string; boundType: string; lb?: number; ub?: number; tick?: number;}[]
        },
        // This determines the range of the whole x-axis
        transform: [
            {
                joinaggregate: [
                    { field: 'lb', op: 'min', as: 'minX' },
                    { field: 'ub', op: 'max', as: 'maxX' }
                ],
                groupby: ['parameterId']
            }
        ],
        params: [
            { name: 'minX', expr: 'minX' },
            { name: 'maxX', expr: 'maxX' }
        ],
        // Parent signal
        signals: [
            {
                name: 'selectedBoxId',
                value: null
            }
        ],
        facet: {
            row: {
                field: 'parameterId',
                type: 'nominal',
                header: { labelAngle: 0, title: '', labelAlign: 'left' }
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            scale: {
                x: 'independent' // Ensure each facet has its own x-axis scale
            }
        },
        spec: {
            layer: [
                {
                    mark: {
                        type: 'bar', // Use a bar to represent ranges
                        opacity: 0.4 // FIXME: This opacity shouldn't be applied to the legend
                    },
                    encoding: {
                        x: {
                            field: 'lb',
                            type: 'quantitative',
                            scale: {
                                zero: false,
                                // Doesn't work with regular domain setting
                                domainMin: { expr: 'minX' },
                                domainMax: { expr: 'maxX' }
                            },
                            title: null
                        },
                        x2: {
                            field: 'ub'
                        },
                        color: {
                            condition: {
                                param: 'tickSelection',
                                field: 'boundType',
                                type: 'nominal',
                                legend: { orient: 'top', direction: 'horizontal', title: null },
                                scale: {
                                    domain: [
                                        FunmanChartLegend.Satisfactory,
                                        FunmanChartLegend.Unsatisfactory,
                                        FunmanChartLegend.Ambiguous
                                    ],
                                    range: ['#1B8073', '#FFAB00', '#CCC569']
                                }
                            },
                            value: '#D3D3D380'
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    mark: {
                        type: 'tick',
                        thickness: 4
                    },
                    params: [
                        {
                            name: 'tickSelection',
                            select: { type: 'point', fields: ['boxId'] },
                            on: [
                                {
                                    events: 'click',
                                    update: 'datum.boxId'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    // Trying to override the parent signal with the scoped signal
                    signals: [
                        {
                            name: 'selectedBoxId',
                            value: null,
                            on: [
                                {
                                    events: { signal: 'tickSelection' },
                                    update: 'tickSelection'
                                }
                            ],
                            push: 'outer'
                        }
                    ],
                    encoding: {
                        x: {
                            field: 'tick',
                            type: 'quantitative',
                            title: null
                        },
                        color: { field: 'boundType' },
                        size: {
                            condition: { param: 'tickSelection', value: 20, empty: false },
                            value: 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };


Decided to use an event listener instead of a signal listener which just gives me the data of whatever I click on.
